# How to intercept keystrokes on the virtual keyboard?

Tags: android, surfaceview, virtual-keyboard

How to intercept button presses virtual keyboard in SurfaceView? Doing so. But nothing is impossible. Help please.

```
InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
inputMgr.showSoftInput(mySurface, 0);

public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, View.OnTouchListener, OnKeyboardActionListener {...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement TextWatcher class and set it up for all inout fields you are going to control. Unfortunately you can't implement generic soft keyboard presses interception. Look [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Comment: I need to catch it in the press SurfaceView. I do not have to Activity EditText.